# Laravel error with upload dropzone

Tags: laravel, upload

I have this code:

```
 public function getUpload()
{
    return View::make('foto/upload');
}

public function postUpload()
{
   $file = Input::file('file');
   $filename = $file->getClientOrginalName();
   $path = 'uploads';
   return $file->move($path, $filename);
}
```

Here views:

```
{{Form::open(array('url' => 'foto/upload', 'class' => 'dropzone'))}}
```

{{Form::close()}}

After upload, display 'X', but how I can display this error? Or what I should fix?

Answer (score -1):

You got a typo. It is "getClientOrIginalName"